# Elastic Beanstalk AWS Rails Bundle Install Failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my rails app using AWS and Elastic Beanstalk. My deployment worked but the health is at a 'red' status - error 11 (bundle install failed).

I tried: 
$ gem update bundler
$ bundle package --all

Still the same error.

```
# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
# ruby "2.4.1"
+ '[' -d /var/app/ondeck/vendor/cache ']'
+ bundle install
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.
Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.16.0) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.1). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching https://github.com/mshibuya/remotipart.git
sh: git: command not found

Retrying `git clone 'https://github.com/mshibuya/remotipart.git' "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/cache/bundler/git/remotipart-f9606ede17c5ca255592b042ebded6ea195ac779" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` due to error (2/4): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'https://github.com/mshibuya/remotipart.git' "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/cache/bundler/git/remotipart-f9606ede17c5ca255592b042ebded6ea195ac779" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /var/app/ondeck has failed.sh: git: command not found

Retrying `git clone 'https://github.com/mshibuya/remotipart.git' "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/cache/bundler/git/remotipart-f9606ede17c5ca255592b042ebded6ea195ac779" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` due to error (3/4): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'https://github.com/mshibuya/remotipart.git' "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/cache/bundler/git/remotipart-f9606ede17c5ca255592b042ebded6ea195ac779" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /var/app/ondeck has failed.sh: git: command not found

Retrying `git clone 'https://github.com/mshibuya/remotipart.git' "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/cache/bundler/git/remotipart-f9606ede17c5ca255592b042ebded6ea195ac779" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` due to error (4/4): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'https://github.com/mshibuya/remotipart.git' "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/cache/bundler/git/remotipart-f9606ede17c5ca255592b042ebded6ea195ac779" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /var/app/ondeck has failed.sh: git: command not found

Git error: command `git clone 'https://github.com/mshibuya/remotipart.git'
"/opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/cache/bundler/git/remotipart-f9606ede17c5ca255592b042ebded6ea195ac779"
--bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /var/app/ondeck has failed.
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to install git.
You can create a file .ebextensions/git.config in your rails app:

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
```

Then try to deploy again

Comment: You sir, are a hero

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Load Balancer target group uses "/" for the health check. Make sure your rails app responses to that endpoint with 200 status or you can update the health check path to a relevant one.